# How do I install my operating system onto an LVM partition on a clean computer?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, operating-systems, lvm

I have just finished building a small home server and came across LVM as a powerful tool to use to manage disk partitions. I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 onto an LVM partition but none of the articles I have read explain how to do this from a blank PC, they assume the OS is already installed. This makes sense though since they use utilities provided by the OS.

So I wanted to know whether it's possible to set up an LVM partition before permanantly installing the OS and then install the OS onto that partition.

Thanks